# Modify item creation date programmatically

Tags: buckets

How do I update the item creation date programmatically for migrated content? As the content items are created programmatically, the created date is always the current date when the script is being executed.

I would like to modify the date of item creation so that my item bucketing rules are executed accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Just set it:

```
var itemToHack = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/YouPath");
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    itemToHack.Editing.BeginEdit();
    itemToHack[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Created] = Sitecore.DateUtil.ToIsoDate(DateTime.MinValue);
    itemToHack.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/ncelico/25b939b4fe7d647e6431

Comment: I want the item created date (read only) created by item:created event handler to be updated in my database so that item bucketing rules are running against that date. This logic will update the created date in the statistics section and when new version is created, then item will move to different bucket as item creation date will be new.

Comment: Then set your system time before creation lol. You're working the wrong problem here. In the code you use for migration, set the created date to what you want.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I think the EndEdit() should have the value false for the UpdateStatistic parameter as on Save, it will re-update the date. EndEdit(false, false)

Comment: Not the created date. Updated, yes.